# How do I check the iOS target version in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, conditional-compilation

I am currently working on an iOS app that targets iOS 9. Due to the age of this target version, I must work with older APIs and sometimes have to add workarounds for bugs in older versions.

I would like to make my code a bit easier to maintain, and preemptively mark parts that need to be refactored once the target version changes. Right now I am using TODO comments, but `#warning` directives would be nicer as they are better visible.

Is there a way to use an `#if` or `#ifdef` directive to check for the iOS target version of the app so that the warning will only appear once the target version changes?

Comment: If I understood you correctly you must read [this](https://medium.com/practical-ios-development/some-practical-uses-for-xcode-build-schemes-and-build-configurations-swift-e50d15a1304f), it helped me a time ago. You can define a schema and build a logic depends on which one selected.

Comment: @ChooGoo The link you mentioned is interesting, but I have already something similar set up for internal testing w/ different targets. Unfortunately, it does not say anything about checking for the target version.

Comment: sorry I got you wrong. Maybe you wanna use ‘if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {}’?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the value of the `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` preprocessor macro:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 100000
#endif
```

That literal `100000` is the value of `__IPHONE_10_0` from `<Availability.h>` but, as the comment there recommends, you should use the literal value, not the symbolic constant.

Comment: Thank you, but I decided that it is safe for me to use the `__IPHONE_x_y` macros: Since the App Store requires a minimum Xcode/SDK version that definitely has the macros, it makes my code more readable.